# If $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x \to 0}f(x + c) = L$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

The claim is as follows:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L$, then $\lim_{x
>  \to 0}f(x + c) = L$.

My attempt:

Suppose $\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L$. Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Then, there exists $\delta > 0$, such that if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0 < |x - c| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$.

Now, consider the number $y = x-c$ which is obviously a real number so that $x = y + c$. Then,

$$0 < |x -c| = |y + c - c| = |y| < \delta$$

and this thus implies:

$$|f(x) - L| = |f(y + c) - L| < \varepsilon$$

which further implies:

$$\lim_{y \to 0}f(y + c) = L$$

Relabelling $y$ as $x$ concludes the proof.

My question is, is this proof valid? Because it just doesn't feel convincing enough for me. I hope someone can show me where I did wrong.

Comment: There is no problem whatsoever. Your proof is right. What feels not convincing?

Comment: Slight technicality: It'd read more cleanly if you started the same, picking $\delta>0$ given $\varepsilon>0$ and then let $y$ be arbitrary such that $|y-0|=|y|<\delta$ and then defined $x=y+c$ and then finished your proof.

Comment: @DavidJaramillo I feel like as if it was... too easy (?) to just consider the number $y = x - c$ and in the last step, to relabel $y$ as $x$. Thank you for your feedback anyways!

Comment: @WoolierThanThou beautiful thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course it is completely right since all boils down in a simple change of variables $x=y+c$ such that

$$x\to c \iff y\to 0$$

and your rigorous way to derive that by the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit is correct.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!